# Something like windows taskbar in c#

Tags: taskbar, c#, winforms

I want to simulate something like windows task bar in c#.
I want a bar on bottom of a form (i mean mainform) .when i open new form,the form name place on bar and when i open another new form,the new form name place on bar and ...
In other hand ,when i click on the form name on bar,that related form be active.
What can i do?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with a ToolStrip - you can dock it to the bottom of your form.

You could add ToolStripButtons for each new form you openand set the DisplayStyle to show text.

Then you can handle clicks on the buttons, of course you'll have to set it so the ToolStripButtons get added and removed dynamically in your code. It's a bit of work, but I reckon it's all there for you.